# Widget display in theme

Tags: plugins, customization, widgets

I just changed theme and I had a custom made widget. the problem now is that in the widget is not visible, I think this is due to not call with "the_widgetXXXX".

How can I see the "official" name of the widget?

Thank you in advance,

JM

Comment: have you set the widget in a sidebar ?

Comment: Yes, I installed the plugin, activated it in the sidebar, but it does not show up in the page itself. Forgot to add that issue is not being visible in website page :).